# Error when convert Http.Error to String with toString in Elm 0.19

Tags: elm

I am working on an Elm task to decode the JSON from API. The problem I met is the decoder I've written is not matched the JSON so I want to show the error. But I cannot convert the error message from `#Http.Error#` type to `#String#` type in Elm with `toString` function. Here is the code:

```
type Model =
  Loading
  | Failure String
  | Success (List WishlistItem)
  | NoData

update msg model =
  case msg of
    GotItems (Ok result) ->
      (Success result.data.wish_list_items, Cmd.none)
    GotItems (Err errorString) ->
      (Failure (toString errorString), Cmd.none)
                ▔▔▔▔▔▔▔▔
```

The error was:

> NAMING ERROR - I cannot find a `toString` variable:
>
> 168|       (Failure (toString errorString), Cmd.none)

I try with `Basics.toString` but it not work. Can anyone help me to point out the problem?

P/s 1: I am using Elm 0.19

P/s 2: And is there another way to find the problem when decoding the JSON with `NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline` package? I tried with `Debug.log` but it just printed the `function` and have no idea how to debug. It's really hard to know where is the problem.

Comment: `toString` was moved to [`Debug.toString`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Debug#toString) in Elm 0.19

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're getting back an [`Http.Error`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#Error), it will have five possible values:

```
type Error
    = BadUrl String
    | Timeout
    | NetworkError
    | BadStatus Int
    | BadBody String
```

If it's an issue with JSON decoding, it'll be `BadBody`, and the `String` will be the error message from the JSON decoder.  You might want a function like this:

```
errorToString : Http.Error -> String
errorToString error =
    case error of
        BadUrl url ->
            "The URL " ++ url ++ " was invalid"
        Timeout ->
            "Unable to reach the server, try again"
        NetworkError ->
            "Unable to reach the server, check your network connection"
        BadStatus 500 ->
            "The server had a problem, try again later"
        BadStatus 400 ->
            "Verify your information and try again"
        BadStatus _ ->
            "Unknown error"
        BadBody errorMessage ->
            errorMessage
```

`toString` was removed in Elm 0.19. There is now [`Debug.toString`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.2/Debug#toString), but it cannot be used in production applications (i.e. when `--optimize` is passed to `elm make`, it will fail when it finds `Debug.toString`)